# Map entries size is already 1 before setting the map value

Tags: javascript

I am printing a Map object before and after setting the map value. Before setting the map value, the map size is 0, which is correct, but the entries size is already 1.

**script.js**

```
const map = new Map();

console.log('Before calling map.set');
console.log(map);

console.log('After calling map.set');
map.set('key1', 'value1');
console.log(map);
```

**Console**

```
Before calling map.set
Map(0) {size: 0}
[[Entries]]
0: {"key1" => "value1"}
size: 1
[[Prototype]]: Map

After calling map.set
Map(1) {'key1' => 'value1'}
[[Entries]]
0: {"key1" => "value1"}
size: 1
[[Prototype]]: Map
```

I tried to `map.get('key1')` before calling `map.set` and it returns undefined correctly.

In the first `console.log`, I was expecting the entries size to be 0, similar to the map size as I have not called `map.set('key1', 'value1')`. I do not understand why the entries size is already set before the map value is set.

Comment: The `console()` API does weird things, especially in Chrome.

Comment: The console logs a reference to your object. When it changes after having already been logged, the originally logged object also changes (when you expand it to view the Map's contents)